# AngularJs: How to change submit function in a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive (confirmation dialog) and I've used that many times in another scopes and appropriate controllers.
How can I change the submit function `1approveConfirm()` to another submit function, for example, `2approveConfirm()`, or `3approveConfirm()`, each time when I set `$scope.showConfirm` (to show this dialog).

```js
app.directive('confirm', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: false,
    controller: function($scope) {}
    },
    template: '<div id="popUp" ng-show="showConfirm"> \
         <div id="popUpDialog"> \
         <div class="title">{{text}}</div>\
          <div style="height:30px"></div>\
          <div class="clearfix buttons-container"> \
              <div class="btn btn_pass pass_canc" ng-click="close()"><span>Cancel</span></div> \
              <div class="btn btn_pass" ng-click="1approveConfirm()"><span>Ok</span></div> \
          </div> \
          </div> \
        </div>'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the approveFunction like below and assing to it teh function you want.

```
$scope.1approveConfirm = function (){ BLABLA };

$scope.2approveConfirm = function (){ BLABLA };

$scope.approveFunction = $scope.1approveConfirm;
```

Comment: can't use numbers as leading character for object property and use dot notation. Will throw errors. Javascript compiler wants to treat it as a decimal

Comment: good idea, thank you, but in each controller this dialog directive might be showed many times, therefore, i need show the dialog each time with another submit function.

Comment: number before function name only for example, guys, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

**With function scope variable**

you could add a function scope variable with `'&'`

```
app.directive('confirm', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
         confirmFunc: '&'
    },
    controller: function($scope) {}
    },
    template: '<div id="popUp" ng-show="showConfirm"> \
         <div id="popUpDialog"> \
         <div class="title">{{text}}</div>\
          <div style="height:30px"></div>\
          <div class="clearfix buttons-container"> \
              <div class="btn btn_pass pass_canc" ng-click="close()"><span>Cancel</span></div> \
              <div class="btn btn_pass" ng-click="confirmFunc()"><span>Ok</span></div> \
          </div> \
          </div> \
        </div>'
  }
});
```

and use the directive like

`<confirm confirm-func="approveConfirm1()"></confirm>
<confirm confirm-func="approveConfirm2()"></confirm>`

where `approveConfirm1`and `approveConfirm2` are functions in your controller

```
$scope.approveConfirm1 = function(){ 
    console.log('confirmed');
}
```

**Without scope variables**

the function which switches the `showConfirm` boolean must also change the function which is called on `ng-click`

```
$scope.submit = function(data){
   $scope.showConfirm = true;
   if( /* get something from data */ ){
      $scope.approveConfirm = function(){
         console.log('approved1');
      };
   }else{
      $scope.approveConfirm = function(){
         console.log('approved2');
      };
   }
}
```

(use approveConfirm() instead of 1approveConfirm() inside the template)

Comment: If you introduce isolated scope, don't forget the `{{text}}`